# Check If a Duplicate Entry exists in Access from .NET

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, ms-access

I want to check if an entry already exists or not in Access Database. And Through my research I've succeeded to get some code for this, but it's giving me some errors. Can you point me in the right direction in achieving my desired code.

Here's my Code:

```
Dim commandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS FROM ESRRegister WHERE ID = '" & IDtxt.Text & "'"
    Using (conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Database\Database.accdb"))
        Using ("select = New OleDbCommand(commandText, conn)")
            conn.open()
            Dim count = Convert.ToInt32("select.ExecuteScalar()")
            If count > 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Already Exists!", "ALI ENTERPRISES", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Else 'Your insert code cmd.CommandText = "insert into ESRRegister (Dt,ID)VALUES ('" & Dttxt.Text & "' , '" & IDtxt.Text & "')" queryResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar() MsgBox("Added Successfuly") 
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
```

It would be great if you provide a little explanation for the code, bcoz i'm new to the .NET

Thank you very much

Comment: What error do you get? at what line?

Comment: In the 2nd line bro... "Using (conn "........... The Error is conn .... It says that the conn is not declared

Comment: seems to me your `using`, `OleDbCommand` and `Convert.ToInt32` syntax are wrong.

Comment: oh is it... can u suggest me what should i use bro... i don't want to use sql coz this App is purely offline... and I only want to use Access

Comment: See my answer. [Here is some sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) you can learn from

Comment: I got a few errors bro when I copied ur code... The errors are "Select, count and queryResult"..... Let's go with one by one bro.. Should I declare select in the public class or somewhere else???

Comment: Sorry bro.. i'm new to the VB. so... please bear with me.... In the 3rd line which is like "Dim cmd" ... i'm getting error, which is asking me that "a ) is expected". So I Inserted a ")" but then i'm getting another message ... which is ... "Variable Cmd hides a Variable in an enclosing block".......

Comment: remove the '(' in the line, so that a')' will not be expected

Comment: Tried it bro, earlier itself... I got the error message "End of Statement Expected" .... Don't know what's wrong wid this one particular line. I'm banging my head over it

Answer (score 0):

```
'The SQL instruction as a string
commandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS FROM ESRRegister WHERE ID = '" & IDtxt.Text & "'"
'Open the connection to the Database
Connection.Open()
    'Use the SQLinstruction to create an OleDBcommand
    Dim mySQLCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(commandText, Connection)
    'Perform the SQL-instruction
    Dim count as integer = CInt(mySQLCommand.ExecuteScalar)
    mySQLCommand.Dispose() 'Clean the command object
Connection.Close() 'Close/Clean connection
```

Comment: Hi bro, thanks for the code .. but i need this in the MS-Access and not SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim commandText As String = "SELECT NZ(COUNT(*),0) FROM ESRRegister WHERE ID = '" & IDtxt.Text & "'"
Using conn as New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Database\Database.accdb")
dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand(commandText, conn
    conn.open()
    Dim count as intiger = Convert.ToInt32(Cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    If count > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Already Exists!", "ALI ENTERPRISES", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Else
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into ESRRegister (Dt,ID)VALUES ('" & Dttxt.Text & "' , '" & IDtxt.Text & "')" 
        Dim queryResult as Variant = cmd.ExecuteNonQueryr() 
        MsgBox("Added Successfuly") 
    End If
End Using
```

`select` is a saved word in VB.net, I changed the name of the `OleDbCommand` to `Cmd`